# Configurable default view layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor

In Asp.net MVC Razor we can use the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to define the default layout for our views. That is fine, but why did we loose the web.config setting that was available with web forms engine in `system.web > pages.masterPageFile` setting?

Why is that important? **Because web.config allow automatic environment transformations.**

### Manual solution

Of course we can put the default layout name in either `appSettings` and refer to that in the `_ViewStart.cshtml` or if we have application specific configuration section add additional property which makes things a bit more clear and polished...

**But is there any other way that doesn't include code?**

Asp.net MVC team should add the `layoutFile` configuration setting to `system.web.webPages.razor > pages` element, shouldn't they?

### The main question is

Am I missing something that is built-in and I don't know about? Something that requires no code at all similar to WebForms engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Asp.net MVC team should add the layoutFile configuration setting to
>   system.web.webPages.razor > pages element, shouldn't they?

Feel free to open a ticket on the MS Connect site.

But while waiting for your ticket to be analyzed by the development teams and probably added in a future version of the ASP.NET MVC framework and the WebPages you could always do the following in your `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Layout"];
}
```

and then define the layout in your web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Layout" value="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Another possibility is to write a custom razor view engine in which you set the layout dynamically.

Comment: Yes that what I anticipated in my *Manual solution*... And that's what I'm doing. Well not exactly the same, because I have a custom configuration section. But it does a similar thing. **Still** it requires code. A tiny amount of it, but it does. In WebForms engine it didn't at all. Not a single line. Configuration was provided. And the same should be here as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there something else you would like to ask? If not, I am afraid that Stack Overflow should not be used to open bugs and feature requests for some particular products. Those requests should be sent directly to the author of the product you are using.

Comment: Not really. I just wanted to know whether I was missing something. There's obviously no built-in solution... The idea wasn't to raise a bug or feature request but more whether I don't know about some feature.

Comment: No, you are not missing anything.

Comment: I can't delete the question since you provided an answer... Hence I added the main question, so it is constructive and fulfils SO requirements.

Comment: I never said that your original question is not constructive and doesn't fit the SO requirements. It's not me that voted to close. I provided an answer to it.

Comment: Oh sorry. I thought you voted it to be closed based on your first comment... If it wasn't you, then no worries. If it gets closed let it be...